# How to overcome Bundle resolve conflict when running specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler

I just added `rspec` but get a bundler conflict when I try and run the specs, this does not happen if I run rake tasks or start the server.

```
bundle exec spec

/<snip>/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:280:in `resolve': You have requested: (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  nokogiri >= 0

The bundle currently has nokogiri locked at 1.5.0.
Try running `bundle update nokogiri`
```

I've tried running `bundle update nokogiri` and removing `Gemfile.lock` and rerunning `bundle install`. I've even tried `rvm gemset empty` and starting afresh.

Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/1342979

Gemfile.lock: https://gist.github.com/1342981

JRuby: 1.6.2
Rails: 3.0.10
Bundler: 1.0.21

Answer (score 0):

It seems running `rspec` instead of `spec` works...